# Display a direction route on Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

how I can display a direction through Waypoints on a Leaflet map.

I used "leaflet-routing-machine" but I can not view the route

```
L.Routing.control({
   waypoints: [
      L.latLng(52.5002237, -2.94),
      L.latLng(52.5002237, -0.949),
      L.latLng(52.5002237, -1.949)
   ], 
   autoRoute: true,
   routeWhileDragging: true,
}).addTo(map);
```

any idea or example plz

you can find a complete example here (https://codepen.io/mahmoud-nb/pen/RZzNYr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your console errors. The request to router.project-osrm.org failed:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)

Comment: thanks, well seen @IH8, there exists another method to display the direction on a map leaflet

Comment: what is the other method? @Mahmoud